# How do I correctly parenthesize nested function calls?

Tags: haskell, syntax, parentheses

Given these two functions:

```
drex :: (Int,Int) -> [[String]] -> String

rcgmove :: String -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)
```

When called like this:

```
drex ((rcgmove b (x,y)) xs)
```

Is an error, because `xs` is `rcgmove`'s third argument.  However, I want `xs` to be `drex`s second argument.  How do I do this?

Comment: function arguments should not be inside () when calling drex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> xs pretends like rcgmove function's third argument, and gives error. However I want xs to be drex function's second argument as you can guess. How can I give xs as drex's second argument?

Just remove the outermost parentheses:

```
drex (rcgmove b (x,y)) xs
```